# Can I offer more than the base amount in a deal?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

When I attempt to offer the AI energy, a flat amount of 30 energy appears under 'My offers'.
I do not see an option or key binding to increase or decrease this value. The AI on the other hand can request much more or less than 30 energy. This also applies to other resources.

Left clicking this box under my offers has no affect. Right clicking the box removes the offer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You can simply click in the box where the number is and edit it. You'll need to then press 'what will make this deal work' or similar to update the offer and see what the AI makes of your request.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out the cursor is very hard to see! Clicking the number value DOES allow modification of the value.